# Generating unique but readable names in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a service in which every user will be assigned a unique name, when he first uses the service.  I wish to generate this name, rather than getting the user to set it up.  Also, I want the name to be somewhat readable and memorable rather than sound like a GUID or a timestamp.  Essentially I want this to be something like the Xbox gamertag.

I know that there will never be more than a 1000 users so maintaining the uniqueness would not be a problem (another reason why I can afford to avoid GUIDs)

I am thinking of taking some adjectives, nouns etc. from the dictionary and generating random but unique combinations of those.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do they need to have a fixed limited size?

Comment: I'd go with your idea - feed in a dictionary of words to use, pick 3 random ones, put them together, insert into the DB table with a unique constraint on the name column (handling the constraint violation to generate a new one) and you're good to go.

Comment: So what is your question: "does this approach work for me" or "I don't know how to take and concatenate random strings from several lists" or "where do I get strings" or something else?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" is a discussion question. Please edit to be more specific as to what you're asking us to help you solve - as it is, the question should be closed as "not constructive".

Comment: I find "adjective + noun" fairly easy to remember: "HotCat" - who wouldn't remember that? (But see the other commends for why I voted to close.)

Comment: While it would be interesting question (as also shown by upvotes) it does not contain answerable question.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a corpus of English language n-grams (say of three letter sequences) and use them to generate words that look like English, but are actually completely gibberish. This kind of data is essentially random, but has a softness for the nature of human language and memory.

[This is similar to what I'm talking about](http://nlpb.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/experiments-with-statistical-language.html), except it combines entire words into sentences probabilistically. I was thinking more of doing it by composing letter sequences into imaginary words.

**EDIT** actually [this page](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/random-words.html) discusses what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a code example to fully approach your problem. In case it doesn't solve it, please try to be more specific in your question. Pass to the following method an instance of the `System.Random` class and a list of words (your dictionary).

```
static string GetGuid(Random random, IList<string> words)
{
    const int minGuidSize = 10;
    const int maxGuidSize = 15;
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (builder.Length < minGuidSize)
        builder.Append(words[random.Next(words.Count)]);
    return builder.ToString(0, Math.Min(builder.Length, maxGuidSize));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this list of 10 000 random name:
http://www.opensourcecf.com/1/2009/05/10000-Random-Names-Database.cfm

or use this website to generate a random list of firstname:
http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php

Safe way. maintain the list of remaining non used names.

Easy way (also very scalable) but unsafe. Rely on the unlikelyhood that 2 users randomly get the same id.

I would try to get 3 or 4 lists of about a thousand modalities and then randomly picking one value in each list. That would make about 10E12 possibilities which is enough to avoid collision for 1000 users.

JohnLampMartin2212